# Do I need to rebuild the python library in Docker container if I change one file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was using cleverhans library to do my project.

However, class CarliniWagnerL2 provided in the current version of [cleverhans/attacks.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/attacks.py), is actually missing in the version in Docker.

So I tried manually compile the current version python file to .pyc file and run the following

```
docker cp host_address containerID:/address/
```

to replace the old file with new file.

I have tested that the file in docker has changed to my current version.

However, when I try to import class CarliniWagnerL2 from the cleverhans, same error saying that

```
from cleverhans.attacks import CarliniWagnerL2
ImportError: cannot import name CarliniWagnerL2
```

Do I need to rebuild the container?

Also, since [cleverhans](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans) does not provide me the DockerFile and other things, if I need to rebuild the python library, how should I rebuild the image?

Thanks

Comment: Try rebuilding and then check

Comment: @TarunLalwani How should I rebuild the container if I do not have Dockerfile or docker-compose?

Comment: which image are you using as of now?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using the container called goodfellow/competition:cpu

Comment: You can run `docker history --no-trunc goodfellow/competition:cpu` and see each individual command that was used to build the image. Take it from there or contact original author for the Dockerfile. You can get his email address also in the history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try building your image.

Create a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM goodfellow/competition:cpu

# Copy your file in
RUN cp host_address containerID:/address/
```

Then do a `docker build` and use that image instead.